# git diff shows differences from master, but pull request says no differences

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

I have a local branch called `dev` that I want to merge into master. I ran `git add --all`, `git commit -m <message>`, `git push origin dev`. I then ran `git diff --name-status master` and it listed a bunch of added added and modified files. I then went to try and create a PR on Bitbucket, and got the following screen:

[image]

As well, if I try to `git add` `git commit`, and `git push` again, it says "Everything up-to-date". And if I try to delete `dev` with `git branch -d dev`, it gives me this warning: "error: The branch 'dev' is not fully merged"

**What I Want to Know:**

Why is it that `git diff --name-state master` shows differences between `dev` and `master` and `git branch -d dev` says `dev` is not fully merged, but `git push` and making a pull request on Bitbucket indicate that there are no differences between `dev` and `master`?

**Update:**

I ran `git checkout master` and then `git merge dev`, and this solved my problem. But I still don't understand why my previous approach ^^ didn't work. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: At this point it may be too late to diagnose things, but if you run `git log --graph --oneline --decorate dev master origin/dev origin/master` and cut-and-paste the output—especially the output from the time the problem was occurring—that would be (or would have been) helpful. (Now that it's fixed, the information we need might be gone.) One bit that is suspicious: the screenshot refers to `development/appointment-fixes`, not `dev`.

Comment: I agree with torek. It looks like the pull request was to merge development/appointment-fixes into master.